# PHP isn't working in file without extension

Tags: php

I had this setup:

```
images
    image1.jpg
    image2.jpg
header.html
about
    index.php
    image3.jpg
```

But going to MyWebsite.com/About gave it an extra slash on the end. I decided to go with the solution of creating a file called about in my home directory:

```
images
    image1.jpg
    image2.jpg
header.html
about
aboutfiles
    image3.jpg
```

The problem is that now this file won't let me use .php:

```
<?php include('header.html');?>
```

It's not showing the header file. What can I do to make this work?

Comment: You need an apache `mod_rewrite` module, or it's analogue, rather than use technique, that you have described.

Comment: Could you show the full `PHP` code of your `aboutfiles` file.

Comment: shouldn't it be `../header.html`?

Comment: No, because the file is in the same directory.

Comment: you created an `about` file with no extension? Have you modified apache to tell it to treat files without an extension as php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your web server does not recognize the filename "about" as a php document. You have three options

1. Use a ".php" extension on your page document, such as "index.php" which will run your php scripting.
2. Install a solution such as mod_rewrite that will translate urls such as /about to a file actual like "about.php".
3. Adjust your servers mime-type for php documents. Learn more about MIME types here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Properly_Configuring_Server_MIME_Types

The first solution is the simplest and easiest, in any document you use PHP, the extension should be .php

Answer (score 1):

About the `mywebsite.com/about` issue, it's more an Apache configuration issue. You have to tell Apache that index.php should be an index file.

Comment: There is no index.php file, he created an about file not a directory.

Comment: read carefully: there was an index.php file. he tried to do something else but it was fine to have a index.php file in the "about" folder.

Comment: Yes he did have an index.php file and he removed it. He now wants the about file to run as a php file.

Comment: Wonderful. Next time my index.php file is not recognized as an index file on a web server, i will try this solution instead of configuring properly Apache.

Comment: I'm not saying his methodology is correct. He is worried that mywebsite.com/about turns into mywebsite.com/about/ because it was a directory. In reality he needs to learn to use rewrite, his index.php was working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can configure your Apache (or IIS) to use whatever Extensions to process PHP-Code.
You can define `.ThisIsAPHPFile` as valid extension, if you want.

However, Directorys are always reflected with a trailing `/`: `www.example.com/dir1/` (Browsers not always showing the trailing `/`) while files have an extension: `www.example.com/dir1/index.html`.

So, from what i see, you want to use `www.example.com/about` but showing the about-FILE ?

Therefore you can use rewrite Engines of your Webserver. Either have a look at mod-rewrite (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html), when using Apache, or (one possibility) ISAPI-Rewrite (http://www.isapirewrite.com/docs/), when using IIS.

Answer (score 1):

If you edit your virtualhost directive in your apache conf file, you can add the following:

```
DefaultType application/x-httpd-php
```

This will tell apache to send web paths that do not end in an extension to render using the php engine.

Therefore, /about would act as if it was about.php.  Another potentially more useful approach is to name the file about.php on the server, and allow referencing it without the .php in the url.  For this, you would configure it the opposite way.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```